# XSLT Check the sum of colwidth for each tgroup and add new attribute to table

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XSLT and it is working as expected; now I need to adjust it so that I can get the sum of all colwidth for each tgroup, which will allow me to add a new class to the parent table for formatting purposes later.
Using the below XSLT I have been checking the value of the @cols=”” on the tgroup element but it is not very accurate as the @colwidth value. Some small tables may have more 4 columns, which get them treated as medium or big tables. 
The goal is to add attribute: `@tablesize="bigtable"` for each tgroup whose coldwidth total is equal or greater than 400pt, `@tablesize="mediumtable"` for tgroup whose total colwidth values are equal or greater than 250pt, and tgroup with colwidth value under 249pt add `@tablesize="smalltable"`.

I haven’t found a straight forward way of achieving this that’s why I am asking.
Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic
  PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Topic//EN" "topic.dtd">
<topic xmlns:ditaarch="http://dita.oasis-open.org/architecture/2005/" id="topic-id" ditaarch:DITAArchVersion="1.2">
    <title>My Tables</title>
    <body>
        <p>Some test tables that need to be transformed.</p>
        <table frame="none" id="table_t4k_bgk_sn">
            <title>Test 1 - Medium table</title>
            <tgroup cols="4">
                <colspec colname="c1" colnum="1" colwidth="75pt"/>
                <colspec colname="c2" colnum="2" colwidth="75pt"/>
                <colspec colname="c3" colnum="3" colwidth="75pt"/>
                <colspec colname="c4" colnum="4" colwidth="75pt"/>
                <thead>
                    <row>
                        <entry/>
                        <entry/>
                        <entry/>
                        <entry/>
                    </row>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <row>
                        <entry>This cell 1</entry>
                        <entry>Cell 2</entry>
                        <entry>Cell 3</entry>
                        <entry>Cell 4</entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry>Test 2</entry>
                        <entry>Test 3</entry>
                        <entry>Test 4</entry>
                        <entry>Test 5</entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry>Test 7</entry>
                        <entry>Test 8</entry>
                        <entry>Test 9</entry>
                        <entry>Test 10</entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry>Test 12</entry>
                        <entry>Test 13</entry>
                        <entry>Test 14</entry>
                        <entry>Test 15</entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry>Test 17</entry>
                        <entry>Test 18</entry>
                        <entry>Test 19</entry>
                        <entry>Test 20</entry>
                    </row>
                </tbody>
            </tgroup>
        </table>
        <table frame="none" id="table_qhj_dgk_sn">
            <title>Test 2 - Big table</title>
            <tgroup cols="7">
                <colspec colname="c1" colnum="1" colwidth="75pt"/>
                <colspec colname="c2" colnum="2" colwidth="75pt"/>
                <colspec colname="c3" colnum="3" colwidth="75pt"/>
                <colspec colname="c4" colnum="4" colwidth="75pt"/>
                <colspec colname="c5" colnum="5" colwidth="75pt"/>
                <colspec colname="c6" colnum="6" colwidth="75pt"/>
                <colspec colname="c7" colnum="7" colwidth="75pt"/>
                <thead>
                    <row>
                        <entry/>
                        <entry/>
                        <entry/>
                        <entry/>
                        <entry/>
                        <entry/>
                        <entry/>
                    </row>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <row>
                        <entry>Test 1</entry>
                        <entry>Test 2</entry>
                        <entry>Test 3</entry>
                        <entry> Test 4</entry>
                        <entry>Test 5</entry>
                        <entry>Test 6</entry>
                        <entry>Test 7</entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry>Test </entry>
                        <entry>Test </entry>
                        <entry>Test </entry>
                        <entry>Test </entry>
                        <entry>Test </entry>
                        <entry>Test </entry>
                        <entry>Test </entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry>Test </entry>
                        <entry>Test </entry>
                        <entry>Test </entry>
                        <entry>Test </entry>
                        <entry>Test </entry>
                        <entry>Test </entry>
                        <entry>Test </entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry>Test </entry>
                        <entry>Test </entry>
                        <entry>Test </entry>
                        <entry>Test </entry>
                        <entry>Test </entry>
                        <entry>Test </entry>
                        <entry>Test </entry>
                    </row>
                </tbody>
            </tgroup>
        </table>
        <table frame="none" id="table_zcb_fgk_sn">
            <title>Test 3 - Small table</title>
            <tgroup cols="2">
                <colspec colname="c1" colnum="1" colwidth="75pt"/>
                <colspec colname="c2" colnum="2" colwidth="75pt"/>
                <thead>
                    <row>
                        <entry/>
                        <entry/>
                    </row>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <row>
                        <entry>Test </entry>
                        <entry>Test </entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry>Test </entry>
                        <entry>Test </entry>
                    </row>
                </tbody>
            </tgroup>
        </table>
    </body>
</topic>
```

Here is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[tgroup]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="tgroup/@cols &gt;= 5">
                    <xsl:attribute name="tablesize">bigtable</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </xsl:when>

                <xsl:when test="tgroup/@cols &gt;= 3">
                    <xsl:attribute name="tablesize">mediumteble</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </xsl:when>

                <xsl:when test="tgroup/@cols &lt;= 2">
                    <xsl:attribute name="tablesize">smalltable</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your `*[tgroup]` template with this...

```
<xsl:template match="*[tgroup]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="tablesize">
            <xsl:variable name="width" select="sum(tgroup/colspec/number(replace(@colwidth,'[^0-9]','')))"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$width >= 400">
                    <xsl:text>bigtable</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$width >= 250">
                    <xsl:text>mediumtable</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text>smalltable</xsl:text>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>        
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Daniel, this does exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms256160%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in you choose with XPath like `tgroup/colspec/@colwidth`

Before that you need to convert @colwidth to a number, by replaceing the *pt* with nothing. There are more generic solutions for conversation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891008/xpath-extract-numeric-value-out-of-string)